# For a subset of 5 vertices find P(all edges between these vertices are present in G)

Tags: probability, graph-theory

```
For a random graph, G, on n vertices's, each possible edge is present independently with probability k, 0 <= k <= 1.

I seek P(all edges between these vertices's are present in G)
My thoughts so far

If we have the empty subset, p = 1
If we have a one element set, p = 1
If we have a two element set, p = k
If we have a three element set, p = k^3
If we have a four element st, p = k^6
If we have a five element set, p = k^10.

If the above is correct, then I can capture the probability as the following:  P = k^(n C 2)
```

However, this only works for two - five element set. If I have a
    one or two element set the following if incorrect. If I am understanding everything correctly up to this point, how can I capture the other two cases?

Is the only possibility a piecewise defined function?
If n=0 or n = 1, 1
Otherwise, k^(n C 2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, your formula works in all cases because:

```
n C 2 = 0, for n < 2
```

And thus:

```
k^(n C 2) = k^0 = 1, for n < 2
```